# How to write a unit test in Unity?

Tags: unity, testing, unit-testing

is there a tutorial and patterns to write unit tests in Unity ?

Should we use the classical c# way and test the code or should we test the interactions in UI ? If so how?

Comment: First link on google : https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/production/unity-test-tools     -     And 2nd one : https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/07/28/unit-testing-at-the-speed-of-light-with-unity-test-tools/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity 2017.2

Unity has a feature called Unity Test Runner which is an integration of NUnit with the Unity Editor.

You can access it through the menu: **Window > Test Runner**

For more information, see the documentation in the [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/testing-editortestsrunner.html)